# Memcache: multiple set / serializing

Tags: php, memcached

I have a question about setting and retrieving memcached variables. Say, I have 5-10 objects with 10 attributes and I want to save those attribute in memcached - what is considered to be more efficient - saving object through serialization or multiple set for each attribute?

Obviously it's a payoff between:

- memory size + greater traffic(due to greater string size) and;
- connection time.

I'm using php with memcached lib.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Memcached library use serialization for PHP data anyway (except numbers and strings), so, usage of serialize is preferable. But if you really want to write your own "serialization" mechanizm which saves all attributes separately (this attributes values are strings/numbers or other objects?) you can use http://php.net/manual/ru/memcached.setmulti.php

Comment: yeah, but watch a comment below - it's actually a stacked execution. I solved my problem by switching caching system to redis.